# Can I keep my car on UK plates while studying in New Zealand?

Tags: new-zealand, vehicle-registration

I'm considering going to New Zealand for university, however I want to drive my car on its current UK plates while I'm there.  Is it possible?

Comment: Have you looked at the cost of getting your car to NZ from UK? It's going to be very high.

Comment: @DJClayworth Yes, I've looked around for a few quotes. It's quite expensive but I'd rather take my car with me than leave it here for a couple of years.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can, for a while. (Not long enough to get a degree, though.) From [Number Plates on the NZTA site](https://www.nzta.govt.nz/roads-and-rail/research-and-data/fascinating-facts/number-plates/):

> **Overseas visitor registration plates** – on vehicles brought in by visitors. So long as the vehicle displays plates from its home country, visitors’ cars can drive on New Zealand roads without paying registration and licensing fees. The vehicle must remain licensed in its own country, but have a current New Zealand warrant of fitness (WoF) or certificate of fitness (CoF). The car owner must also pay the ACC levy. This exemption is allowed for 18 months or until the vehicle is sold or if the visitor becomes a permanent resident in New Zealand.

You will need to submit a [Notice of temporary vehicle import by overseas visitor (MR2C)](https://www.nzta.govt.nz/resources/temp-vehicle-import-visitor/index.html)  form.